# Making a kind of switch case for inherited classes by type

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator

I've got a base class calls:

```
class item
{
public:
    item();
    virtual string act()=0;
};
```

and a few classes that inherit from this one;

```
class food:item
{
public:
    food();
    string act();
};

class ant:item
{
public:
    ant(unsigned int new_ant);
    ~ant();
    string act();
};

class anthill:item
{
public:
    anthill();
    string act();
}
```

then I've got a list that serves as a container of several instances of those classes.

I iterate through the list.

Now I've to use different functions depending on the type of the instance that are hidden behind the Iterator.

but I can't find a way to distinguish between e.g. an ant and food

I've  tried comparisons with typeinfo 
as well as

```
ant* test = dynamic_cast<ant *>((*i)); // returns nullptr even though debug says i is an ant
```

Comment: Use a variant instead of runtime type info to construct a switch by type.

Comment: Apart from anything else, you need to use public inheritance.

Comment: This is what virtual functions do.  Are they not working polymorphically?

Comment: Also, if some code outside the class needs to distinguish types, read about the "Visitor pattern".

Comment: Show how you create the "list".  It's possible you are suffering from slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ant* test = dynamic_cast<ant *>((*i)); // returns nullptr even though debug says i is an ant
```

That's because your classes use `private` inheritance. Change them to use `public` inheritance.

Use

```
//           |
//           v
class food : public item
{
  public:
    food();
    string act();
};
```

Comment: Mind = blown.  I had no idea that `dynamic_cast` cared about access modifiers.  But sure enough, Standard says " In both the pointer and reference cases, the program is ill-formed if *`cv2`* has greater cv-qualiﬁcation than *`cv1`* or if `B` is an inaccessible or ambiguous base class of `D`."

Comment: @BenVoigt, it makes sense since a derived class pointer cannot be converted to a base class pointer automatically when `private` inheritance is used. It makes sense that `dynamic_cast` won't work to go from base class pointer to derived class pointer. Now that I have said it aloud, I wonder how the OP got the pointers to the base class to begin with. Hmmm...

Comment: Yeah I can see where respecting access modifiers would be desirable.  I'm just not sure it is worth the cost (because now use of `dynamic_cast` from inside class members needs to use a different set of runtime type information than one outside).  I think the wording "program is ill-formed" is actually giving the toolchain the option of ignoring access modifiers.   Also, hmmmm indeed

Comment: @StephanPich, glad I was able to help.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I don't think it really needs a different set of RTTI. The accessibility would be checked statically based on the types involved in the dynamic cast expression. No different than any other expression really ([similar restrictions apply to static casts too](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#3)).

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's not so simple, because `dynamic_cast` does [cross-casts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35960031/103167)

Comment: @BenVoigt - d'oh, of course. Even says as much in [dynamic.cast.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.dynamic.cast-8). I guess there really are no free lunches.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by using containers of type_info hash codes to function pointers, For example a language interpreter implemented operator resolution by having maps like the following:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, add_func*>fnsAdd = boost::assign::map_list_of
    (std::make_pair(typeid(integer_value).hash_code(), typeid(integer_value).hash_code()), (add_func*)&integer_value_integer_value_Add)
    (std::make_pair(typeid(integer_value).hash_code(), typeid(real_value).hash_code()), (add_func*)&integer_value_real_value_Add)
```